# How can I fix this hyper terminal command-line error code: 800A0404?

Tags: compiler-errors, jscript, windows-terminal

I was trying to configure my Hyper Terminal Command-Line through Edit -> Preferences and this popped up [Microsoft JScript compilation error: 800A0404](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgtIV.png) Please, I need help to resolve the problem (I'm using Window 8). Thanks in advance.

I have experimented all the knowledge i found on the internet, but still could not fix the problem.